# how do i stop NSTextField blocking right clicks for NSTableView rows?

Tags: macos, cocoa, tableview

As the title suggest, I've enabled right clicks for my tableview with customized rows. Anywhere there is an `NSTextField`, it blocks the right click.

is there a `userInteractionEnabled` equivalent for cocoa like on the iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I though I probably needed to subclass everything in my `NSTableCellView` subclass, but I just needed to override `-(NSView*)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint` method in my `NSTableCellView` subclass to return self.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to right click on text fields within my custom view based table view cell. Here is how I configure it:

```
NSTextField *tf = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

self.textField = tf;

self.imageView.autoresizingMask=NSViewWidthSizable;
self.textField.editable=NO;
self.textField.selectable=NO;
self.textField.drawsBackground=NO;
self.textField.bordered=NO;
self.textField.bezeled=NO;
self.textField.target=self;
self.textField.action=@selector(textDidEndEditing:);
[self.textField.cell setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle];
```

Also, make sure you are setting the `-menu` property of `NSTableView` and not the cell view to enable to menu. (I don't know if that will make a difference to your issue but it is how I do right clicking in a table view.)

Comment: I had to subclass a tableviewcell, and override menuForEvent to get right clicks to even work. Setting a menu for tableview.menu did not enable right clicks for me.

Comment: I set my menu in interface builder if that means anything.